# Android: How to capture button press event for contact create app of device

Tags: android, button, capture, pressed

I want to invoke my application once user creates / updates contact from his device.
i.e once user hit "**Done**" button. is it possible ? If possible please provide sample code or link.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to invoke my application once
>   user creates / updates contact from
>   his device. i.e once user hit "Done"
>   button. is it possible ?

No, it is not possible, in terms of detecting the GUI event. You can set up a data observer on the `Contacts` (or `ContactsContract`) content provider, and attempt to find out those things that way, though I do not know how well that works.